# Regex - Find filename from various subdirectories

Tags: regex

I have a function that is cross-platform between Windows and Unix, and I need to pull the filename from something like:

```
../../Media/foo-blah\\bar-name\\
```

Where the separators can be forward slash `/`, backslash `\` or double backslash `\\`.  I need a regex that will give me just the filename minus any trailing slashes.

The string *may not* end with any slashes at all, or it may end with any of the above.

I'm stuck using a proprietary scripting language for an application, so I can't run a shell, or Perl, but I can do the matching in steps.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hm. Above path can't be a Windows-path, can it? On Unix-like systems, the filename would be `foo-blah\\bar-name\\ `. Trailing slashes only occur for directories, which are files in a wider sense (`everything is a file`).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want a regex that looks like the god of punctuation barfed all over it,

1. String replace `\` with `/`.
2. String replace `//` with `/`.
3. Strip trailing `/` if there is one.
4. Split on the last `/`.

(If you write a regex, you will end up with something full of `[\\\\\\\\|\\\\|/]`.)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe one of these

`(?:^[.]*|[\\/]?)\s*(\w+?)\s*[\\/]*\s*$`
or
`(?:^[.]*|[\\/]?)\s*([^\\/]+?)(?<!\s)\s*[\\/\s]*\s*$`
or
`(?:^[.]*|[\\/]?)\s*([<valid-filename characters>]+?)\s*[\\/]*\s*$`

Yep, looks like a bunch of `/////\\\\\\\\\`'s to me too.